# different "python" and "python3" versions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My `python --version` is Python 3.9.6
And my `python3 --version` is  Python 3.10.8

I believe because of this I have a problem with running flask applications in VsCode. When I run one I receive `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask` error, however, I did install flask module

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.2.2)
```

I know that sometimes this problem is caused by the wrong interpreter version, I tried all of them but no one worked

[image]

Does anybody know what is the reason for my error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code to print out the currently used interpreter.

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Then use the command to install flask for the current interpreter.

```
<pythonpath> -m pip install flask
```

[image]

Referencing this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this either of this commands;
---python3 -m venv venv

--python -m venv venv
---py -m venv venv

if that doesn't work then get your Python version and make sure you are installing the package using the correct Python version.

But If the  error persists, restart your IDE and development server/script.

You can check if you have the Flask package installed by running the pip show Flask command.

Comment: how can I install packages for specific python version? because my "flask" is located in python version 3.11. However, when I try to get python or python3 versions in the terminal it shows 3.9 and 3.10 correspondingly